# Sort an array based on string size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm completely stuck on this. My aim is to create a method which lets me sort an array based on the length of the string.

I manage to sort it descending but it can't get to sort depending on the string size.

```
def sort_by_length(anArray)
  anArray.sort { |x,y| y <=> x }
end

a = ["twoish","one", "treeishish"]
sort_by_length(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use:

```
def sort_by_length(anArray)
  anArray.sort { |x,y| x.size <=> y.size }
end

a = ["twoish", "one", "treeishish"]
sort_by_length(a)
```

or even better

```
> ["twoish", "one", "treeishish"].sort_by(&:size)
=> ["one", "twoish", "treeishish"]
```

if you might have `nil` value, you better compact the array first

```
> ["twoish", "one", "treeishish", nil].compact.sort_by(&:size)
=> ["one", "twoish", "treeishish"]
```

Comment: Sweet, thans Astreal!

Answer (score 1):

```
def sort_by_length(array)
  array.sort { |p,q| p.size <=> q.size }
end
```

Anyway this version will break with nil values. This will handle that problem:

```
def sort_by_length(array)
  array.sort { |p,q| p.try(:size) || 0 <=> q.try(:size) || 0 }
end
```

Comment: You should mention that `try` only works with rails.

Comment: I don't understand where the `nil` values are coming from but perhaps you could make use of the fact that `s.to_s => s` if `s` is a string and `nil.to_s => ''`.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["twoish","one", "treeishish"]
arr.sort_by {|x| x.length}
#=> ["one", "twoish", "treeishish"]
```

also:

```
arr.sort_by(&:length)
#=> ["one", "twoish", "treeishish"]
```

The way you tried, it should be:

```
arr.sort{|x, y| x.length <=> y.length}
#=> ["one", "twoish", "treeishish"]
```

Comment: With the difference between `sort` and `sort_by` being that `sort_by` will run more quickly because of the embedded computation of `length` in the block. Use `sort_by(...).reverse` to create the fastest version of the descending sort.